# Making a timer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, countdown

I have a problem in Unity. I need a countdown in my project. But this countdown will count 2 times. For example, 3 seconds a job will be done, 2 seconds another job will be done and these works will continue.

Comment: show what you have done so far,then only someone can suggest you

Comment: More than what you've done, you'd need to explain further what you need. Are the different counters running at the same time or is one waiting for another to be done before starting?

Comment: @Everts I believe he tried to explained in the answer he gave below. So I believe this is for you: "consider an object. When the program start, turn right for 3 seconds, after turn left for 1 second. they will repeat continuously. two counters will follow each other."

Comment: Why don't you put some code for your question?

Comment: Sounds like something you should put in coroutine.

Comment: @kit i dnt  have a same code, so i asked

Answer (score 4):

## Couroutines (and more Coroutines)

Coroutines do exactly the thing you want to do.

```
private IEnumerator Countdown2() {
    while(true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2); //wait 2 seconds
        //do thing
    }
}

private IEnumerator Countdown3() {
    while(true) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); //wait 3 seconds
        //do other thing
    }
}
```

You then start them off by calling in your `Start()` method (or where ever):

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Countdown2());
    StartCoroutine(Countdown3());
}
```

Note that both countdown methods will do their thing forever unless one of three things happens:

1. `StopCoroutine(...)` is called, passing in the reference returned by `StartCoroutine`
2. The countdown function itself returns (which will not happen unless it breaks out of the infinite `while(true)` loop)
3. The coundown function itself calls `yield break`

Also note that in the event both coroutines should resume at the same time (e.g. at 6 seconds) coroutine 2 will execute first (as it was started first), unless some other effect intervenes (e.g. one of the loops has another `yield` instruction, one of the loops is terminated, etc).

Comment: As I understand, in this case tasks in each Coroutine are executed at the same time. Am I wrong?

Comment: Coroutines are *synchronous,* meaning that they are never executed at the exact same time (i.e. separate threads and causing Concurrent Modification Errors), but they *can* run at the same *point in time* between frames, one after the other. See [the flowchart](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/monobehaviour_flowchart.svg).

Comment: I think in this case you would have each method running every 5 seconds, am I wrong? Perhaps you want to do Wait 1 second and then increment i then do modulo arithmetic.

Comment: @Aron No, task 1 runs once every 2 seconds and task 2 runs every 3. Refactoring to achieve other solutions ("do X for N seconds" or "do X, then Y") are also possible, with relatively minor modifications of the coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Based in the example of use you gave where an object first turn right, then turns left:

> consider an object. When the program start, turn right for 3 seconds,
>   after turn left for 1 second. they will repeat continuously. two
>   counters will follow each other.

Below I give you two timers which are executed sequentially: first one will last 3 seconds and the second one other one 2 seconds. Once one counter finish the other one will starts, this will be repeated in an infinite loop.

```
float counterTask1 = 3f;
float counterTask2 = 2f;
float timer;
bool chooseTask;

void Start(){
    //Initialize timer with value 0
    timer = 0;
    chooseTask = 1;
}

void Update ()
{
    // Add the time since Update was last called to the timer.
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    // This will trigger an action every 2 seconds
    if(chooseTask && timer >=  counterTask1)
    {
        timer -= counterTask1;
        chooseTask = 0;
        #Do Task 1 Here
    }else if(!chooseTask && timer >= counterTask2)
    {
        timer -= counterTask2;
        chooseTask = 1;
        #Do Task 2 Here
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for. In any case there are lot of questions already asked about timers in Unity. Check some of them:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=timer+in+Unity

Comment: Two things: 1) this will function, but is not extendable. 2) you should subtract the duration from the counters when triggered, otherwise you'll get some desynchronization (`3.0518` seconds on timer, reset to zero, lose `0.0518` seconds of elapsed time: after 20 iterations, the loop will be running a second late!)

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks for the feedback, but I am not sure how to subtract the duration. I believe your answer will be more efficient and it will have my +1, but just for the example the user gave I though this sequential timers could be an approach simple enough .

Comment: @MehmetGüneş sorry that was a typo, let me edit the answer

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre instead of `timer = 0f` it would be `timer -= counterTask1` (or `counterTask2`).

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks, I will edit the answer with this information

Comment: i am sorry the say that, it is not working, not rotating :/

Comment: @MehmetGüneş add in your question the code you are using to rotate or whatever you are doing. The timer I wrote is working, you can try it with a log or print to debug it.