# How to make a Power Up last for a certain amount of time after collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a weird little runner game and I am trying to add a power-up that will allow the player to jump for a short while, maybe 10 seconds.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {

public PlayerMovement movement;
public GameObject PowerUp;
public float jumpUpForce = 5000f;
public float jumpBackForce = 1000f;
public Rigidbody rb;


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
        movement.enabled = false;
    }

    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "PowerUp")
    {
        PowerUp.SetActive(false);
        JumpPower();
    }
}

void JumpPower()
{
    if (transform.position.y < 2)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, jumpUpForce * Time.deltaTime, -jumpBackForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is that when the player collides with the power up and runs the JumpPower() function, it just calls it once so it cant detect the input of the left shift behing held down (I think).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You may use coroutines. Every time you pick power-up, you cancel already existing coroutine (if one exists) and start new, which will handle the timing. This is how it would be done in my way:

```
public PlayerMovement movement;
public GameObject PowerUp;
public float jumpUpForce = 5000f;
public float jumpBackForce = 1000f;
public Rigidbody rb;

bool doWeHaveJumpPowerUp;
Coroutine cor;
public float timer;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    doWeHaveJumpPowerUp = false;
    timer = 10.0f;
}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        movement.enabled = false;

    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "PowerUp")
    {
        PowerUp.SetActive(false);
        if(cor != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(cor);
            cor = null;
        }
        cor = StartCoroutine(JumpPower());
    }
}

IEnumerator JumpPower()
{
    doWeHaveJumpPowerUp = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
    doWeHaveJumpPowerUp = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (doWeHaveJumpPowerUp)
        if (transform.position.y < 2)
            if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
                rb.AddForce(0, jumpUpForce * Time.deltaTime, -jumpBackForce * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

EDIT: if you want more types of power-ups this is how you want to add them:

```
public PlayerMovement movement;
public GameObject PowerUp;
public float jumpUpForce = 5000f;
public float jumpBackForce = 1000f;
public Rigidbody rb;

bool doWeHaveJumpPowerUp;
Coroutine cor;
public float timer;

// 2nd power up
bool doWeHaveFlyPowerUp;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    doWeHaveJumpPowerUp = false;
    timer = 10.0f;
}


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        movement.enabled = false;

    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "PowerUpJump")
    {
        PowerUp.SetActive(false);
        if (cor != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(cor);
            cor = null;
        }
        cor = StartCoroutine(JumpPower());
    }

    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "PowerUpFly")
    {
        PowerUp.SetActive(false);
        if (cor != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(cor);
            cor = null;
        }
        cor = StartCoroutine(FlyPower());
    }
}

IEnumerator JumpPower()
{
    doWeHaveJumpPowerUp = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
    doWeHaveJumpPowerUp = false;
}

IEnumerator FlyPower()
{
    doWeHaveFlyPowerUp = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
    doWeHaveFlyPowerUp = false;
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (doWeHaveJumpPowerUp)
        if (transform.position.y < 2)
            if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
                rb.AddForce(0, jumpUpForce * Time.deltaTime, -jumpBackForce * Time.deltaTime);
    if (doWeHaveFlyPowerUp)
    {
        //Fly power up logic
    }
}
```

In both of these examples power-ups cancel already existing power-up. You should plan how you want power-ups to work:

- should the character be able to have a lot of power-ups at the same moment.
- should newly picked up power-up of the same type you already have extend the duration or refresh it.

Also, at this moment you will be able to have only one powerUp. If you want more you have to write a generator for them (if you want them to be random) or put them by hand if you want them in somesort of order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with coding for Unity but, for what you want to accomplish, it sounds like you need to run a Timer.

I'd typically place the following code in the Form.Load() but, since this isn't an actual winforms app, you'd likely know better where to place it for run-time.

```
int t = 0; // Add this as a variable within the class to provide sufficient scope
Timer power_up_timer = new Timer();
power_up_timer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 ms = 1 second
power_up_timer.Tick += power_up_timer_Tick;
```

Then add the Tick Event anywhere within the class:

```
private void power_up_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (t == 10) { /* End the power-up */ t = 0; power_up_timer.Stop(); }
    else { t++; }
}
```

Then, in your power-up initialization block, add:

```
power_up_timer.Start();
```

However you can get that to work out in the code, that's pretty much how it's done.

Comment: While Timers are available (Unity does have access to ask C# features and libraries), Unity's coroutines are a better solution here.

Comment: @Draco18s - Interesting. It's essentially a while loop operating as a timer. I can dig it and I'm not about to argue semantics with a built-in feature. ;)

Comment: Timers are geared towards (safe) multithreading, but Unity is a single-threaded application (Jobs are threads, but they're intentionally more limited than true threads, eg, they're Promised to never cause concurrent modification of data), so Unity functions can't be invoked from a child thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run a coroutine!

```
// action is just a function or a method
// if you need that with arguments it would be System.Action< T > action
    IEnumerator TimerRoutine(int seconds, System.Action action)
    {
        int sec = 0;
        float delta = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            delta += Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log(delta);
            if(delta >= 1f)
            {
                sec += 1;
                delta = 0;
            }
            if (sec == seconds)
                break;
            else
                yield return null;
        }

        // this will start your function at the end of the timer
        action();
    }
```

You can call StartCoroutine(TimerRoutine(args)) to start the timer from any MonoBehaviour.

Comment: Uh... `yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds)`?

Comment: @Draco18s - In researching Coroutine, I actually ran across your answer to a similar (but not duplicate) question. It's an interesting way of doing what I've always tasked timers with doing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139259/making-a-timer-in-unity